# MFC: Accessing Views from Mainframe

Tags: c++, mfc, docview

I am trying to access a view inside a splitter from my mainframe. At the moment I have this:

CWnd* pView = m_wndSplitter.GetPane( 0, 0 );

However this gets me a pointer to the CWnd not the CMyViewClass object.

Can anyone explain to me what I need to do in order to access the view object itself so I can access member functions in the form pView->ViewFunction(...);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just cast it:

```
// using MFC's dynamic cast macro
CMyViewClass* pMyView = 
   DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMyViewClass, m_wndSplitter.GetPane(0,0));
if ( NULL != pMyView )
   // whatever you want to do with it...
```

or:

```
// standard C++ 
CMyViewClass* pMyView = 
   dynamic_cast<CMyViewClass*>(m_wndSplitter.GetPane(0,0));
if ( NULL != pMyView )
   // whatever you want to do with it...
```

If you *know* that the view in pane `0,0` will always be of type `CMyViewClass`, then you could just use `static_cast`... but i recommend you don't - no sense risking problems should you ever change your layout.